# I know this question is kind of stupid, but can a person with CIPA(a disease that causes them not to feel pain) feel the burn of hot-sauce/mace?

Tags: pain, disease

So I was thinking whether or not a person that has a disease where they can not feel pain ,like CIPA, basicly be immune to capsaicin i.e. hot peppers, hot sauce, and pepper spray/mace. So what is the truth?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?